# How to I search for a single quote character( ' ) in a text Using LIKE predicate in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to search and select columns where there is a single quote (') present in the text using LIKE or CONTAINS Predicate.

consider the following text : 10011-RIO MARE EXTRA'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST
( Test_Column  VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES
('10011-RIO MARE EXTRA''')

SELECT * 
FROM #TEST
WHERE Test_Column LIKE '%''%'
```

The escape character for ' is ' used twice -> ''.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select * from yourtable where youcolumn like '%''%'
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how this actually works.

Answer (score 1):

Find records with single quotes in the table

```
SELECT *
FROM [tableName]
where Name like '%''%'
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this solves your problem

% **'** % -> Finds any values that have " **'** " in any position

By executing below query you will get the result which have '(single quote) in them

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE "%'%"
```

i have executed the same query [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQR6q.jpg)

Comment: I am getting an error when I run your query in SQL server.

Comment: Error : Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name '%'%'.

Comment: in your query try using "%'%" instead of '%'%' you are using single quote i guess may be that is the problem

Comment: this is just wrong, double quotes cannot be used in sql server

Comment: it is working in mine

Comment: @ShardulSinghGurjar your screenshot doesnt look like sql server, what tool are you using?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I m using adminer extension...  i have tried in sql server as well it is working fine for me

Comment: @ShardulSinghGurjar as you have mentioned you use adminer, i suspect you are using mysql and not sql server